# Safari display: inline-flex not working

Tags: html, css, safari

I stuck with small issue with safari.
I have a code:

```
<div class="row social_link">
   <a><img></a>
   <a><img></a>
   <a><img></a>
   <a><img></a>
</div>

.social_link {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.social_link img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

on Chrome, IE, FF this icons are inline, horizontal. but on Safari they setup vertical, stack one on each other. I found similar problem on stackoverflow but this not help. Maybe you have some experience with this problem?
When I use web inspector on Safari it crossing inline-flex and -bekit-inline-flex. only display what stay is -ms-inline-flexbox

Comment: Which version of Safari? You mention IE, so I must ask. Is this on Windows?

Comment: I use safari 5.1.7 for windows. 
Yes this is under windows.

Comment: As I thought. That is an old version. You can safely ignore it. Safari is currently at v10.0.

Comment: Yes now I read that Apple discontinued safari for windows. This will explain old version

Answer (score 0):

So I remove in class `.social_link` all display and add

```
.social_link a {
display: inline-block;
```

}

This help